# Need to get name from column on one table and match to other column to another table in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have these tables below in access

tblBaseResults is where the base info is.

I use this query to get count of the Activity names in tblBaseResults

```
SELECT tblBaseResults.Activity, Count(tblBaseResults.Activity) AS CountOfActivity INTO tblCountResults
FROM tblBaseResults
GROUP BY tblBaseResults.Activity;
```

This produces my table tblCountResults.

What i need it to bring then Name from tblBaseResults over to a new column on tblCountResults where the Activity matches. Also i would only like to bring over fields that DO NOT contain ?. Some will contain question marks and if thats all there is thats fine. but i would prefer to bring over fields without question marks first.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can different Names have same Activity?

Comment: If you're starting with tblBaseResults, I don't understand why you don't just add the Name field to your query? You'd have to wrap it in brackets ([]) because it's a reserved word, but that would be the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: Yes. different names can have same activity. I could add Name field to original query but how would i choose the one that does not contain "?". also when i tried to add it i was getting more/duplicated results. how would that query look?